# Maths quiz that read/writes CSV files

Tags: python, csv, quiz

Could this code possibly be shortened, or even better be rewritten in the fewest lines of code possible?

```
import csv

import random
import math
import operator as op



name=input("What is your name: ")
print("Hello there",name,"Welcome to the math quiz, you will be asked 10 random questions on Addition, Multiplication and Subtraction")





choice = random.choice(['x','-','+'])
finish = False
questionnumber = 0
correctquestions = 0
Class = "" 


while finish == False:
       choice = random.choice(['x','-','+'])
       if questionnumber < 10 | questionnumber >= 0:
           number1 = random.randrange(1,10)
           number2 = random.randrange(1,10)
           print((number1),(choice),(number2))
           answer=int(input("What is the answer?"))
           questionnumber = questionnumber + 1

        if choice==("+"):
            realanswer = number1+number2
            if answer==realanswer:
                print("Well done that's the correct answer")
                correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
            else:
                print("Unlucky wrong answer")

        if choice==("x"):
            realanswer = number1*number2
            if answer==realanswer:
                print("That's the correct answer")
                correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
            else:
                print("That was not correct")

        elif choice==("-"):
            realanswer = number1-number2
            if answer==realanswer:
                print("That's the correct answer")
                correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
            else:
                print("Unlucky not the corret")

    else:
        finish = True
        print("Well done You have completed the math quiz, Your score was " + str(correctquestions) + "/10 questions.")

while Class not in ("1" , "2" , "3"):
    Class = input("whish class are you in?")

ScoresList = []

if Class == "1":
    with open("class1.csv","r") as class1:
        reader = csv.reader(class1)
        for row in reader:
            ScoresList.append(row)
elif Class == "2":
    with open("class2.csv" , "r") as class2:
        reader = csv.reader(class2)
        for row in reader:
            ScoresList.append(row)

elif Class == "3":
    with open("class3.csv","r") as class3:
        reader = csv.reader(class3)
        for row in reader:
            ScoresList.append(row)
else:
    print("Please enter a valid class")


position = 0 
match = 0


for row in ScoresList:

    if len(row) > 0 and row[0] == name: 
        match = 1
        break
    else:
        position += 1


print(position , match)
if match == 0:
    ScoresList.append([name,str(correctquestions)])
else:

    row = ScoresList[position] 
    if len(row) == 4:  
        del row[1]  
    row.append(str(correctquestions))  

for row in ScoresList:
    print(row)

if Class == "1":
    with open ("class1.csv" , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row)

if Class == "2":
    with open ("class2.csv" , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row)


if Class == "3":
    with open ("class3.csv" , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row) `
```

Comment: I surely am happy that you fell that my answer helped you, but I suggest waiting at least a day before accepting my question to give others a chance to give their suggestion.

Comment: Typo there, "whish class are you in?" :)

Comment: Your indentation is still off. Inside your `while` loop, your `else` block doesn't match with any other block of code.  Please do try to get it exactly right since it matters so much in Python.

Answer (score 2):

#### You surely can shorten it by also improving readability

For example:

```
if Class == "1":
    with open ("class1.csv" , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row)

if Class == "2":
    with open ("class2.csv" , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row)


if Class == "3":
    with open ("class3.csv" , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row) `
```

Becomes:

```
if Class in ("1", "2", "3"):
    with open ("class{}.csv".format(Class) , "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in ScoresList:
            writer.writerow(row) `
```

And, as you do that twice, you can extract it into a function to further avoid duplication.

---

You can also **extract common code out of conditional branches**

```
        if answer==realanswer:
            print("That's the correct answer")
            correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
        else:
            print("Unlucky not the corret")
```

is repeated in all of the `if`s so you can write it just once at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

```
while finish == False:
```

could better be stated:

```
while not finish:
```

though I'd also suggest renaming the variable to `finished`.

**2.**
lines like

```
           questionnumber = questionnumber + 1
```

are better stated as:

```
           questionnumber += 1
```

**3.**
       if questionnumber < 10 | questionnumber >= 0:

...is almost certainly just plain Wrong.  Do you really want bitwise-or there?  If you meant logical-or, python spells it `or`.

**4.** `position` and `match` are redundant; use a sentry value of -1 as the default for `position` and then check against position < 0 to see if a match wasn't found. (if it was, it should be a row number... which is always 0 or higher)

**5.** Don't use reserved words or capitalized words like `Class` as variable names.  Your `Class` is just as appropriately named `class_number`.

**6.** Factor out common filenames.  You read and write to the same filename, but have two copies of the string, which could lead to trouble if you later change one and not the other. Instead store the name in a variable or constant that you can then pass to the various `open` invocations.

**7.** Add some comments.  This breaks the code up into sections, and describes, at least briefly, what each section does.

```
import csv

import random
import math
import operator as op

# Welcome
name = input("What is your name: ")
print("Hello there", name, "Welcome to the math quiz, you will be asked 10 random questions on Addition, Multiplication and Subtraction")

choice = random.choice(['x','-','+'])
correctquestions = 0

# give the quiz
for questionnumber in range(1,11):

    choice = random.choice(['x','-','+'])
    number1 = random.randrange(1,10)
    number2 = random.randrange(1,10)
    print((number1),(choice),(number2))
    answer = int(input("What is the answer?"))

    if choice == "+":
        realanswer = number1 + number2
    elif choice == "x":
        realanswer = number1 * number2
    elif choice == "-":
        realanswer = number1 - number2


    if answer == realanswer:
        print("Well done that's the correct answer")
        correctquestions +=  1
    else:
        print("Unlucky wrong answer")

else:
    print("Well done You have completed the math quiz, Your score was " + str(correctquestions) + "/10 questions.")

# save their score
class_number = None
while class_number not in ("1" , "2" , "3"):
    class_number = input("which class are you in?")

classfilename = "class{}.csv".format(class_number)
ScoresList = []
position = -1

with open(classfilename, "r") as classfile:
    reader = csv.reader(classfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row and row[0] == name:
            player_row = len(ScoresList)
        ScoresList.append(row)

print(position)

if position < 0: # not found in the class
    ScoresList.append([name, str(correctquestions)])
else:
    row = ScoresList[position] 
    if len(row) == 4:  
        del row[1]
    row.append(str(correctquestions))  

for row in ScoresList:
    print(row)

with open (classfilename, "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in ScoresList:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: For some reason when I try the code, it comes up with "name not defined" i cannot see why it is doing this

Comment: name = int(input("What is your name: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 't' is not defined

Comment: @RichardFletcher You're probably using Python 2 where you should use `raw_input`, not `input`. Are you running Python from a different place than before, your original script did use `input`.

Comment: @pjz Just saying the bitwise operator is wrong is only half the advice. Why not also explain how Python uses `or` as its logical operator?